# Is it possible to add endpoints to a running gRPC service

Tags: c++, grpc

Before starting a [gRPC](https://grpc.io/) service we can use [`ServerBuilder::AddListeningPort(...)`](https://grpc.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_server_builder.html#a5bf2d8c40e6b4ca170b9ee927d4db326) to add as many endpoints as we want.

But once the service is started, i.e. after [`ServerBuilder::BuildAndStart(...)`](https://grpc.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_server_builder.html#aa3966340091070dd68fa831a03e1e6ef) is called, is it possible to add one or more new endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem possible. You could instead start a new server with the same set of services.